# Phonegap file writing throws error code 1

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to write a file in android using phonegap cordova 1.5.0. Below is the code snippet. This snippet is working fine in simulator but when I run this on my android mobile it goes till gotFs() then "fail error code" alert of fail() pops up with message

> "fail error code 1"

that means it is failing at line

> `fileSystem.root.getFile("projectFileName", {create: create: true,
>   exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);`

.

code snippet

```
         function onDeviceReady() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
           }

               function gotFS(fS) {
            fileSystem = fS;
            fileSystem.root.getFile("projectFileName", {create: create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail); 
          }

          function gotFileEntry(fE) {
            fileEntry = fE;
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
          }


          function gotFileWriter(writer) {
           .......... file writing code.
          }

         function fail(error) {
            alert('fail error code = '+error.code);
            alert('error '+error);
            console.log(error.code);
         }
```

The simulator avd is 2.3.3 and my device has android 2.3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 fileSystem.root.getFile("projectFileName", {create: create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

to

```
 fileSystem.root.getFile("projectFileName", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```